# How Can I remove a particular product from an completed order in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce plugin.
My requirement is to remove a particular product from a completed order.

I am not able to find any solution yet.

Please help.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Actually, I want to create a new order after removing some items from completed order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer myself. I use the code below and it worked.

```
$order = wc_get_order(35);
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
  if ($item_id == 3) {
    wc_delete_order_item($item_id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is good, no problem… Just for info, the actual and compact way is: `$order = wc_get_order( 35 ); foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) { if( $item_id == 3 ){ wc_delete_order_item( $item_id ); } }` … …  Note that `$item` is not the `$product` objet but the `WC_Order_Item_Product` object and you can get the product object using `$item->get_product();`

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, FYI, the answer has been edited to take your suggestion into account.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the status of the entire order to 'On hold' or 'Processing payment' you can delete seperate items in that order.

Comment: Yes, I have done it as "processing" status but I am unable to delete each particular items. Can you please give the code?

Comment: 'Processing' status isn't good enough. It must be 'On hold' or 'Processing payment'...

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter( 'wc_order_is_editable', 'wc_make_completed_orders_editable', 10, 2 );
function wc_make_processing_orders_editable( $is_editable, $order ) {
 if ( $order->get_status() == 'completed' ) {
    $is_editable = true;
 }

return $is_editable;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26212789)

Comment: my english is weak sorry for that

Comment: This solves another problem, how to make orders with certain states editable via the admin interface, but not really the original question.