# Is it possible to practically update the order items after the order?

Tags: woocommerce, orders

I'm looking for how I can update the items after the order is made. I'm wondering if there is a practical way to do this. For example, I want to remove 1 item after the order is fulfilled. So I want to cancel.
There is a hook for this called [wc_update_order_item_meta.](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-order-item-functions.html#function_wc_update_order_item_meta) Yes, but there are many metas (_qty, _line_total ...) I'm researching if a collective change can be made. But I couldn't find a general, practical solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40889616/13378498

Comment: I saw it. It's talked about canceling "only the whole item" here.

Comment: Can you provide an example bcs i dont understand what you want. The example is showing you how to access order and from there access items in this order. Rest is up to you.

Comment: Thank you. In short, I was looking for a function that does all the operations again in case of partial cancellation. New subtotal, total, tax etc. I guess there is no such thing.